# Java interface and Exception

Tags: java, exception, interface

I have a question in my exam paper where it asks me to write the following interface:

```
<interface> Queue  
size(): int 
isEmpty(): boolean 
isFull(): Boolean 
enqueue(Object) throws QueueFullException: 
dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException: Object
```

This is what I have done:

```
public interface Queue
{
    public int size();
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public boolean isFull();
    public void enqueue(Object ob) throws QueueFullException;
    public Object dequeu() throws  QueueEmptyException;    
}
```

I wanted to know if this is right, mainly the object "enqueue", the paper also asks me to write the code for `QueueFullException` and `QueueEmptyException`, I have done this but I'm not sure if it is right.

```
public class fullException extends QueueFullException {
    public fullException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class EmptyException extends QueueEmptyException {
    public EmptyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `public` keyword in your interface must be written with a lower-case p and you've also made a typo in the name of the `dequeue` method. (It's important to be very precise!).

Comment: The first thing to do to know if code is right is to compile it. If and only if it compiles, the second thing to do is to test it. If and only if the tests fail, then you could ask help. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: And you are probably not supposed to create subclasses of the `QueueFullException` and `QueueEmptyException`; you have to create those classes themselves, not subclasses of those classes.

Comment: If you're supposed to write `QueueFullException` and `QueueEmptyException` then why are you instead writing classes that *extend* those?

Comment: Before turning to StackOverflow turn to `javac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface is right, but the exceptions are wrong. I think you meant:

```
public class QueueFullException extends Exception
{
    public void fullException(String message) 
    {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class QueueEmptyException extends Exception
{
    public void emptyException(String message) 
    {
         super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't compile. And those exception should really be runtime exceptions.

Comment: The contructor name must be equal to the class name.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way, intefaces just have to declare method signatures and you did it properly. Just a few naming issues: the "public" in the method signature should be lower case.
Another naming convention is to use capital letters to indicate classes, so your "fullException" should become "FullException". You didn't provide any info about the Exception classes, if the purpose was to extend the other two then it's correct.

Comment: In fact, there shouldn't even be public modifiers in the interface. All interface methods are implicitely public. The public modifier is redundant.